# Ansible hangs when pulling from vsts git repo

Tags: git, ansible, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Hi I'm attmepting to clone from a vsts git repository (ssh://********/_git/ClouderaAutomation) but ansible seems to just hang when I try. Below is a snippet of the git module being used.

```
name: Clone git repo.
  git:
   repo: "{{ repoToClone }}"
   dest: "/home/vagrant/ClouderaAutomation"
   accept_hostkey: yes
   clone: yes
  become: yes
```

repoToClone is ssh://********/_git/ClouderaAutomation. When i execute 'git clone' cmd directly on the remote servers it clones the repository without issue. However when I attempt to clone via ansible it just hangs with no error, here is the last line of the -vvv logs:

<192.168.33.30> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/9a3517bddd -tt 192.168.33.30 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-lugffujkolhidvafudbyhootlistpyyf; /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494346256.28-165153189526831/git.py; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1494346256.28-165153189526831/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

Comment: is it the only issue with ansible ? and with which user are you able to clone manually on the remote machine ?

Comment: yes its the only issue I'm currently facing with Ansible. For example if I attempt to clone 'https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript.git' with the same ansible module it completes successfully. I was using the vagrant user manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue by including an additional parameter to my Ansible git module, -key_file.

> [Ansible Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html): Specify an optional private key file to use for the checkout.

Full module sample:

```
name: Clone git repo.
  git:
   repo: "{{ repoToClone }}"
   dest: "/home/vagrant/ClouderaAutomation"
   accept_hostkey: yes
   key_file: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
  become: yes
```

Additional requirements:

- Make sure you have generated an ssh keypair (ssh-keygen), I made one without a passphrase due to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136358/ansible-git-module-is-hanging) by the OP.
- Add the public key to the vsts server

Hopefully this helps anyone else who has the same issue.